# OperationalError in SQLite, I can't solve it

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
`sql_create = 'create table cursos '\
'(id integer primary key, '\
'titulo varchar(100), '\
'categoria varchar(140), '\
'requerido varchar(100))'

cursor.execute(sql_create)

recset = [(1000, 'Ciência de Dados', 'Data Science'),
          (1001, 'Big Data Fundamentos', 'Big Data'),
          (1002, 'Python Fundamentos', 'Análise de Dados'),
          (1003, 'Teste', 'Testes')]

for rec in recset:
    cur.execute(sql_insert, rec)
```

---

```
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-d00fefe3c52f> in <module>
      1 # Inserindo os registros
      2 for rec in recset:
----> 3     cur.execute(sql_insert, rec)

OperationalError: table cursos has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied`
```

Comment: Your recs only have 3 fields, but your table has 4 columns. You need to supply as many values as columns if you don't automatically assign them. (Also you apparently have 2 different cursors? If `cursor` and `cur` are isolated, that can be a problem as well.)

Comment: The error message is explicit: you only supply 3 value per record while the table has 4 fields. You should give explicitely the list of provided fields: `INSERT INTO cursos(id, titulo, categoria) VALUES(?,?,?)`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a table with four columns:

```
`sql_create = 'create table cursos '\
'(id integer primary key, '\
'titulo varchar(100), '\
'categoria varchar(140), '\
'requerido varchar(100))'
```

- id
- titulo
- categoria
- requerido

but when you are supplying values, you're only supplying three values per row:

```
recset = [(1000, 'Ciência de Dados', 'Data Science'),
          (1001, 'Big Data Fundamentos', 'Big Data'),
          (1002, 'Python Fundamentos', 'Análise de Dados'),
          (1003, 'Teste', 'Testes')]
```

That's what the error is saying.

You should update your `sql_insert` variable as suggested by Serge Ballesta in the comment on your question to something like:

```
INSERT INTO cursos(id, titulo, categoria) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

which will get rid of the error.